# Count how many variables in a dataset have a value based on a condition

Tags: r, count

```
ID  |V1_h   |v1_l   |v2_h   |v2_l   |v3_h   |v3_l   |v4_h   |v4_l   |v5_h   |v5_l   |Count

1   |1  |3  |1  |1  |1  |1  |1  |1  |1  |1  |5

2   |2  |4  |1  |NA |1  |1  |1  |NA |1  |NA |5

3   |5  |NA |1  |NA |NA |NA |NA |NA |NA |NA |2

4   |NA |NA |6  |5  |1  |NA |1  |1  |NA |NA |3
```

Following are the commands I used to create columns

```
  ID <-  c(1,2,3,4)   
V1_h <-  c(1,2,3,NA) 
v1_l <-  c(1,2,5,NA) 
v2_h <-  c(3,4,NA,NA) 
v2_l <-  c(1,1,1,6) 
v3_h <-  c(1,NA,NA,5)
v3_l <-  c(1,1,NA,NA)
v4_h <-  c(1,1,NA,1) 
v4_l <-  c(1,NA,NA,1)
v5_h <-  c(1,1,NA,NA)
v5_l <-  c(1,NA,NA,NA)
```

I have 11 variables and want to compute 'Count' variable. ID is record ID. V1 to V5 are 5 pair of variables. Each pair has high `(_h)` and low `(_l)` value. 
I want to increase count if a variable (either high or low has a value). As shown in above example in Rstudio.

I want the output which is:
 Count variable will have following values 5, 5, 2, 3.

Comment: @akrun Sorry, I am new to Stackoverflow and hence problem with the code. I have edited the V1_h so that the last one is 3.

Comment: Yes, now it is getting 3.  You can check the solution below

Answer (score 2):

We remove the suffix part of the column names (except the 'ID' column) using `sub`, `split` the dataset (excluding the 'ID' column) based on the changed column name into a `list` of `data.frame`s, loop through the `list` with `lapply`, convert the `data.frame` into a logical matrix (`!is.na(x)`), get the sum of each row (`rowSums`) and check if it is greater than 0 i.e. if there are any non-NA elements in each row.  Then, we collapse, each corresponding `vector` element of `list` with `Reduce` by summing (`+`)

```
df1$Count <- Reduce(`+`, lapply(split.default(df1[-1], 
   sub("_.*", "", names(df1)[-1])), function(x) rowSums(!is.na(x))>0))
df1$Count
#[1] 5 5 2 3
```

NOTE: Here we assume the second column name as 'v1_h' and not 'V1_h'

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = 1:4, v1_h = c(1, 2, 3, NA), v1_l = c(1, 2, 
5, NA), v2_h = c(3, 4, NA, NA), v2_l = c(1, 1, 1, 6), v3_h = c(1, 
NA, NA, 5), v3_l = c(1, 1, NA, NA), v4_h = c(1, 1, NA, 1), v4_l = c(1, 
NA, NA, 1), v5_h = c(1, 1, NA, NA), v5_l = c(1, NA, NA, NA)), .Names = c("ID", 
"v1_h", "v1_l", "v2_h", "v2_l", "v3_h", "v3_l", "v4_h", "v4_l", 
"v5_h", "v5_l"), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: I am getting 6,6,2,3

Comment: It worked, only thing is I didn't get the logic. My data has many more columns and I want to know  on which columns the code is used/run.

Comment: @Swapnil  Added more description.  Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

One other possible solution, would be to use `rollapply` from `zoo` package. Since you only have high and low (i.e. 2 variables for each), then,

```
library(zoo)
colSums(apply(df1[-1], 1, function(i)
                          rollapply(i, 2, by = 2, function(j) sum(!is.na(j)))) > 0)

#[1] 5 5 2 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using the tidyverse. If your dataframe does not contain any other variables you can remove the first row (select).

Basically, we just transform the dataframe into a long format using the gather command. Subsequently, we aggregate the low and high variables (mutate) and count the number of non NA observations for each ID and variable (first summarise). Afterwards we count the number of variables with at least one non NA value (second summarise). Last, we add the calculated values to our dataframe. The rest are just grouping operations.

```
require(tidyverse)

df %>%
  select(ID, v1_h, v1_l, v2_h, v2_l, v3_h, v3_l, v4_h, v4_l, v5_h, v5_l) %>%
  gather(variable, value, -ID) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(variable = unlist(strsplit(variable, "_"))[1]) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  group_by(ID, variable) %>%
  summarise(count = sum(!is.na(value))) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise(sum(count >= 1)) %>%
  .$count -> df$count
```